# Append/Union two table with unidentical column names in RMYSQL(dbsendquery)

Tags: r, sqldf, rmysql

I have 2 dataframes with different column names which i need to append

```
A = c("Q","W","E")
B =c(12,23,31)
df1 = data.frame(A,B)

A = c("R","T","Y")
B =c(3,111,21)
C= c(5,9,3)
df2 = data.frame(A,B,C)
```

I am trying to append two data frames like `rbindlist(data.table)` functionality in `sqldf`

```
samp = rbindlist(list(df1,df2),fill=T)
```

Any modifications in below code

```
samp= sqldf ("insert into df1 select * from df2")
```

The error i am getting is:

> Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
>     table df1 has 2 columns but 3 values were supplied"

Answer (score 0):

We can create dummy column then `UNION ALL`:

```
sqldf("select *, NULL as C from df1
       union all
       select * from df2")

#   A   B  C
# 1 Q  12 NA
# 2 W  23 NA
# 3 E  31 NA
# 4 R   3  5
# 5 T 111  9
# 6 Y  21  3
```

Comment: Thanks..@zx8754 ... can we do with out specifying new column "C" ..?.

Comment: @san1 Why not use rbindlist solution? What is the reason to do it with sqldf?

Comment: Actually I am trying to insert rows in df1   with df2 (which are there in MYSQL)  DB from Rstudio "dbSendQuery(dbcon, "  insert into df1 SELECT * FROM df2")

Comment: @san1 Please update your question to reflect your situation, this is not a sqldf question.

Comment: my idea is to replace sqldf statements in dbsendquey statement..both statements are identical

Comment: @san1 I don't think it is possible without creating temp tables, or altering the table before insert.